# Does Pa Auk Has A Plan To Translate Tipitaka Pali To English?

Tags: pali-canon, meditation, pali-language, translation

I have known about the other translation's versions.

However, I need to know the possibility of translation project especially from Pa Auk.

I also want to know, if it is possible to know, the reason that they do not start the pali to english translation project.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is any Tipitaka translation project at the Pa Auk monastery when the Ven. Sayadaws book Nibbānagāminipaṭipadā remains still to be translated into English.

Comment: Oh! I through the time, I have thinking  that Nibbānagāminipaṭipadā already done in english translation. I like pa auk because of they can answer like commentaries (I understand tipitaka before I met pa auk), so I never done to read Nibbānagāminipaṭipadā.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to answer. 
I think your best option is to try and contact *Pa Auk Forest Monastery*.

[Their contact information can be found here.](http://www.paaukforestmonastery.org/contact.htm)